# EMR Spark thrift server create table: NoRouteToHost

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, emr

Running Spark's thriftserver on top of the hive metastore.

When I execute the following DDL via `spark.sql`

```
create table if not exists test_table
     USING org.apache.spark.sql.parquet
     OPTIONS (
         path "s3n://parquet_folder/",
           mergeSchema "true")
```

The following stack trace is emitted; punchline being that the indicated host ip (eg 172.31.8.86) is non-existent.

```
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No Route to Host from  ip-172-31-13-2/172.31.13.2 to ip-172-31-8-86.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/NoRouteToHost
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:758)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1479)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.delete(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:540)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.delete(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:2044)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:707)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:703)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:703)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply$mcV$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:185)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$createTable$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:72)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createTable(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.createTable(SessionCatalog.scala:226)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableUtils$.createDataSourceTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:501)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:105)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:186)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:167)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:65)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:582)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
  at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:495)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:614)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:712)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2900(Client.java:375)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1528)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1451)
  ... 87 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the external metastore had been created by another EMR cluster. Apparently the hive metastore maintains cluster state (ip addresses).

The immediate solution was to drop the hive database and rebuild with `/usr/lib/hive/bin/schematool`.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this without dropping the hive database by running:

```
hive --service metatool -updateLocation NEW-URL OLD-URL
```

OLD-URL can be retrieved with:

```
hive --service metatool -listFSRoot
```

NEW-URL is the domain of your new cluster master.